# Keeping a table up to date that has been created using a DB Query

Tags: mysql, query, update, table

I have created a new table view for customers, so that when they log in, they only see the information that they need to see...

I used the Query:
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer( SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, ColumnE, ColumnF, ColumnG, ColumnH FROM DB.Table )`

The table populated with the expected results, however when the parent table gets new data added, the Queried table does not update.

Is there a recommended way to keep this table up to date?
Id rather not have to refresh the query every day as the table also has a `WHERE` funchtion where I filter the a specific customer, as a result I have a number of the same queried tables in plac, lone for each customer.

Is there a way for this to automatically update?

Comment: I guess you meant to `create view`, not a table?

Comment: @mustaccio I created a new table via HeidiSQL using the above query to pull information
Creating a view might be what I am looking to do, however, I am looking to give them functionality to export information and I only want them to be able to export the information which I have provided. Im not sure if creating a view would allow for that?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86802/grant-permissions-on-views-deny-select-on-tables