# "ANY command denied to user" when creating a view

Tags: mariadb, amazon-rds, view

We have a read only Amazon RDS database (MariaDB, 10.6.8 and up) that is synced to a production database.

We have a data scientist making views to handle our OLAP use cases.

You can't create a view in a read only database (at least at RDS), so I attempted to create a user in the production database that can only create views. However, attempting to create a view gives this error:

```
create view v_test as select * from tabItem;
ERROR 1142 (42000): ANY command denied to user 'test_view'@'%' for table 'tabItem'
```

It looks like this same user needs SELECT capability; granting that allows the view to be created. (I also thought perhaps it was the `SELECT *` but even doing `select column from ...` didn't work)

That would also allow them to hammer Production by executing the views in production instead of the read only database.

Are there any grants that would allow creating of views, but not executing a select statement or even using the view?

Note this is related to [Grant permissions on views, deny select on tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86802/grant-permissions-on-views-deny-select-on-tables) but slightly different.

Comment: I removed the [tag:mysql] tag, because MariaDB is not MySQL. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed significantly since then. We need to stop thinking of them as compatible or variations of the same product. In particular, [the ANY command](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/operators/ANY/) is not supported by MySQL. It's a feature specific to MariaDB 10.2 and later.

Comment: Thanks Bill - got it. I owe you twice. Is it possible in MySQL to give a user CREATE VIEW but not SELECT? I.e. is this problem MariaDB only?

Comment: It says in https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-view/: _"The CREATE VIEW statement requires the CREATE VIEW privilege for the view, and some privilege for each column selected by the SELECT statement. For columns used elsewhere in the SELECT statement you must have the SELECT privilege."_ So the user that creates the view must have that privilege.

Comment: Subsequently other users can query the view, even if they don't have privilege to query the base table, provided the view was created with `SQL SECURITY DEFINER`. That is, they gain access to the base table through the view, because the view adopts the definer's privileges.

Comment: Right, I saw that, but it's frustrating. We were trying to create a "create only" account such that the user wouldn't accidentally query production. If switching to MySQL vs. MariaDB would have fixed it, we would have.

Comment: I don't think what you describe is an option in either brand of software. MySQL's description of the privileges required in this case is identical: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: Understood. It's unfortunate. I'm seeing evidence in production of long running SQL queries, which are probably coming from these "read only" views. They should be done against the replica. There's no stopping users!

Comment: I'm afraid this is something you will have to enforce in your application code. If by users you mean developers of the application code, then you're SOL. I have also had no success preventing developers from shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: Yup, then we end up having to bandage the feet, right? I did look at doing a separate database with some kind of programmatic replication, but that seems to be more effort when "I told you so" may work when production crashes. Wish us luck.

Comment: @BillKarwin The Plot thickens, I now have to grant DROP permission, because in MySQL nor MariaDB, you can't GRANT DROP VIEW ... but at least I can do it one view at a time.